# How can I fix java.lang.NullPointerException caused by TraceGovernor in Jaspersoft studio plugin?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, eclipse-plugin, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm writing plugin for Jaspersoft studio up-to-date. The plugin crashes, when it is trying to open preview of report. (from the plugin) Stack Trace of java.lang.NullPoinpointerException:

```
com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor.setup(TraceGovernor.java:111)
com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor.initMaps(TraceGovernor.java:118)
com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor.beforeReportInit(TraceGovernor.java:162)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDatasetScriptlet.beforeReportInit(JRFillDatasetScriptlet.java:74)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractScriptlet.callBeforeReportInit(JRAbstractScriptlet.java:176)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:236)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:580)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:119)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Non of code in stack trace is mine. I think it can't load necessary classes. (Jaspersoft studio can load all necessary libraries) Does anyone know, what to do with it please? Many thanks.

---

### Edit

I've found, that it's caused by this property in Jaspersoft studio, that loads extension, that is loading `TraceGovernor`. It's for debugging report, but it isn't compatible with my plug-in.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.governor=com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernorExtensionsRegistryFactory
```

I've solved that by removing it from java package `com.jaspersoft.studio_6.3.0.final.jar\jasperreports_extension.properties`, but I would like some non-destructive method, how to disable this extension.

Comment: It is hard to help you without viewing the code. Did you try to debug? Where did you get the NPE? `I think it can't load necessary classes.` - Did you check the classloader?

Comment: I've added some additional information.

Comment: This should be a bug report filed with JasperSoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant source code is available at:

http://anonsvn:anonsvn@code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/jaspersoftstudio/tags/6_3_0_final/com.jaspersoft.studio/src/com/jaspersoft/studio/debug/TraceGovernor.java

The NPE appears to be the result of an uninitialized `jrConfig` field in the `TraceGovernor` class, which would be initialized had `getJasperReportsContext()` of the `ScriptletFactoryContext context` in the constructor of `TraceGovernor` returned an `instanceof JasperReportsConfiguration`.

You may checkout and navigate the repository to further investigate the reason for the NPE. Otherwise, I can only suggest to file a bug report with JasperSoft.