# JasperReports print pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to use JasperReports to generate a pdf invoice through a serlvet in my application. I installed the JasperReports plug-in through eclipse, and have been running using that, for some reason though my application will not print out my pdf. I'm getting a null pointer that I can't seem to fix.

This is my code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //String type = request.getParameter("type");
    //int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

    String jrxmlFileName = "C:/res/jasper/OrderInvoice.jrxml";
    String jasperFileName = "C:/res/jasper/OrderInvoice.jasper";
    String pdfFileName = "C:/res/pdfs/invoice01.pdf";

    try
    {
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlFileName, jasperFileName);

         // String dbUrl = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
           String dbUrl = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/*MY DATABASE*";
           // String dbDriver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
           String dbDriver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
           // String dbUname = props.getProperty("db.username");
           String dbUname = "*MY DATABASE USERNAME*";
           // String dbPwd = props.getProperty("db.password");
           String dbPwd = "*MY DATABASE PASSWORD*";

           // Load the JDBC driver
           Class.forName(dbDriver);
           // Get the connection
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUname, dbPwd);

        HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put("OrderId", 1);
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFileName, hm, conn).setJasperReportsContext(jasperReportsContext);;

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, pdfFileName);
        conn.close();
    } catch (JRException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The report I am generating takes in one parameter, the Order Id of a particular order to create a invoice for. That's what is set in the HashMap. I found this code on a JasperReports page.

This is the null pointer I've been receiving:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor.setup(TraceGovernor.java:111)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor.initMaps(TraceGovernor.java:118)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor.beforeReportInit(TraceGovernor.java:162)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDatasetScriptlet.beforeReportInit(JRFillDatasetScriptlet.java:74)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractScriptlet.callBeforeReportInit(JRAbstractScriptlet.java:176)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:236)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:582)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:90)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:286)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:759)
at exchange.InvoiceExchange.doGet(InvoiceExchange.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1681)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Ive found this page [How can I fix java.lang.NullPointerException caused by TraceGovernor in Jaspersoft studio plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511505/how-can-i-fix-java-lang-nullpointerexception-caused-by-tracegovernor-in-jasperso)
But I am unable to complete the solution he found.

I've also tried a few different sample codes online, none of which have worked.

Comment: You should post a small simple *jrxml* to reproduce the problem

Comment: com.jaspersoft.studio.debug.TraceGovernor is a class that comes with Jaspersoft Studio, I don't think it was meant to be used outside the Studio application/plugin.  The likely reason for which it is being used in your server application is that you have included a com.jaspersoft.studio*.jar in your application's classpath.  Removing that jar from the application should get rid of the error.

Comment: Thank you @dada67, that was the fix!